# Is there a way to safely override Module#=== for a given type?

Tags: ruby, delegates, monkeypatching

In Rails (version 3.2 at least; I don't have 4 to be able to try there), `ActiveRecord::Base#find` chokes if given a `SimpleDelegator`, even if the object it delegates would otherwise work properly.

The reason for this is that `AR::Base#find` passes values into `AR::ConnectionAdapters::Quoting#quote` while creating an SQL statement, and since it doesn't know what to do with `SimpleDelegator`, it tries to pass it to `YAML.dump`, which raises an exception. `AR` determines how to quote by a `case` statement of classes (ie. `String === value`, etc.).

Now, of course, even if a `SimpleDelegator` contains a `String`, its class is `SimpleDelegator`, so the above check will fail. However, `SimpleDelegator` has a `__getobj__` method, which provides access to the actual object being delegated to:

```
> s = SimpleDelegator.new("test")
#=> "test"
> String === s
#=> false
> String === s.__getobj__
#=> true
```

In order to get around this problem, I could override `Class#===` to take `SimpleDelegator` into account:

```
class Class
  def ===(other)
    return super(other.__getobj__) if other.is_a?(SimpleDelegator)
    super
  end
end

> String === s
#=> true
```

However, this *clearly* does not look like a safe way to go about doing this (I don't know if this will negatively impact anything, but at the least, class equality to `SimpleDelegator` will be broken). On the other hand, this makes it easier to handle other instances of code like that in `AR::ConnectionAdapters::Quoting#quote` which I'm not yet aware of (as opposed to specifically monkey patching `quote` to know about `SimpleDelegator`, for instance).

[`Module#===`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) is a native C method in MRI, and makes use of a method called `rb_obj_is_kind_of`. I had hoped that overriding `SimpleDelegator#kind_of?` might allow me to do what I want to here in a safer manner, but it seemed to have no impact (I guess `rb_obj_is_kind_of` doesn't really have anything to do with `Object#kind_of?`).

Is there any way to do this in a "safe" manner, or am I just stuck monkey patching individual cases as they come up?

Comment: Rather than monkeypatching `Class` I would at least implement `SimpleDelegator#class ; String ; end`. Though it still does not seem to be a perfect solution.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either, unfortunately; while `s.class` becomes `String`, `String === s` still is false.

Comment: Beg your pardon; it looks like I have the class name only checked. But I finally found the weird hack for you, please see an answer within a couple of mins.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may hack around and to cheat the `AR`. It tries to `YAML.dump`? Well, we’ll help it:

```
class A < SimpleDelegate
  def initialize *args
    @s = 'voilá'
  end
  # required by YAML (Psych)
  def encode_with coder
    coder.tag = nil
    coder.represent_scalar(nil, @s)
  end
end

require 'yaml'

puts YAML.dump(A.new)
# ⇒ --- voilá
```

Now `AR` should be able to dump it and voilá. The `encode_with` method might be put into `CheatModule` to include it whereever you need to cheat `AR`:

```
module DelegateYamler
  def encode_with coder
    coder.tag = nil
    coder.represent_scalar(nil, __getobj__)
  end
end
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This assumes that the the payload of the `SimpleDelegator` is a `String`; it can in fact be anything. And while this may get around the crash for strings, it doesn't really fix the problem. It'll generate an invalid SQL query and fail that way.

Comment: Anyways, I already have a working monkey patch for `AR#find` to use `SimpleDelegator`s properly, so that's not the problem; I'd like to find a way to do so without having to monkey patch *each* instance this comes up, if possible.